# I'm trying to push to the GitHub repository from Visual Studio Code, but I can't authenticate

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-push, git-authentication

When I push the code to GitHub from Visual Studio Code I get the errors:

> remote: Repository not found. 
> fatal: Authentication failed for

How can I fix it?

Comment: @manson i m using visual studio code

Comment: what you used in your username option your `github username` or `email address` ?

Comment: Yes, this is a super FAQ (understandably because it affects so many), but Stack Overflow can't produce a solution or workaround that actually works.

Comment: Or maybe it can. A candidate for a canonical question is *[fatal: Authentication failed for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).